# Passing value from servlet to javascript in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I am new to java programming and I am trying to pass a value from servlet to javascript in jsp using struts.

servlet class-

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;

public class handler extends org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction{

    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

    public ActionForward Add(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception {

        actionFileAndDB obj=new actionFileAndDB();
        JSONArray list=obj.view();
        request.setAttribute("jsonArray",list);

        System.out.println("this is being called");

        String s="Karthikeyan";
        request.setAttribute("myname",s);       

        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

jsp-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONArray"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>View</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="operations.do">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select value="s"  name="dropdown">
                            <option>VIEW</option>
                            <option>Database</option>
                            <option>File</option>
                            <option>Both</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Add" name="actionMethod" onclick="javascript:viewData();" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="actionMethod"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="actionMethod"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>


        <p id="p1">
        </p>




        <script type="text/javascript">
            function viewData()
            {
                var c="Hello";
                document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=c;

                //JSONArray j=request.getAttribute("jsonArray");
                //document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=j;

                //String s=request.getAttribute("myname");
                //document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=s;

                event.preventDefault();

            }
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

When I uncomment the getAttribute("myname"), nothing gets displayed from the paragraph tag.I wanted to know if there is any way to retrieve the value from servlet to javascript without using JQuery or Ajax for the time being.

//edited with the complete code shown-

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>view.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

struts-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>

    <action-mappings>

        <action path="/view" forward="/view.jsp"/>

        <action path="/operations" type="handler" parameter="actionMethod">
            <forward name="success" path="/view.jsp"/>
        </action>

    </action-mappings>



</struts-config>
```

view.jsp and handler.java is already shown

```
actionFileAndDB.java

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;

public class actionFileAndDB{

    public actionFileAndDB(){}

    public JSONArray view() throws ClassNotFoundException{

        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase", "root", "");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT * FROM employee order by id";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

                obj.put("id",rs.getString("id"));
                obj.put("name",rs.getString("name"));
                obj.put("mobile",rs.getString("mobile"));
                obj.put("email",rs.getString("email"));
                obj.put("dept",rs.getString("dept"));

                list.add(obj);

                //System.out.println("db: "+list.get(0));
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        }catch(java.sql.SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERRRORHELLO");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is getAttribute("myname")?

Comment: in jsp..I have commented it..if I uncomment it...nothing from the paragraph tag gets displayed on the browser.

Comment: Post your complete code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add java code inside `scriplet` `<% %>` in jsp

```
  function viewData()
    {
        var c="Hello";
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=c;

        <% JSONArray j=request.getAttribute("jsonArray"); %>
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="<%=j%>";

        <%String s=request.getAttribute("myname");%>
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="<%=s%>";

        event.preventDefault();

    }
```

Refer this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html) for scriplets

Comment: "null" is getting displayed on the webpage and "Hello" is not getting displayed.

Comment: @Karthikeyan are your action class `handler` is called properly before displaying the `view.jsp` ? are you getting the debug prints 'this is being called' in logs?

Comment: I am sure there are no issues with the handler class.I checked the log files. There no debug prints 'this is being called' in logs.

Comment: Try accessing the page using the url `http://<server>/operations.do?actionMethod=Add`.

Comment: it is working fine if I give the URL http://<server>/operations.do?actionMethod=Add. . But I want to access it in view.do itself. Is that possible?

Comment: You have not specified any action in `view.do`. so, it is directly redirected to the `view.jsp`, Either you need to write an action class for 'view.do' and set the request attributes or you can change the `view.do` param as `<action path="/view" forward="/operations.do?actionMethod=Add"/>`

Comment: In view.jsp, I have <form action="operation.do"> and I have action class for operation.do. So is it necessary for an action for view.do?

Comment: If you are going to get data from the server `ex database`, you need to have an action class, which fetches the data from server. You can use same action class for `view.do` & `operations.do` or write a `new one`, but you should have an action class that talks with the database and get results for 'view.do'.

Comment: If I had to use JQuery and Ajax, how should I do it?

Comment: It depends on the usage, If you want to load the url content inside a `div` you have to use jquery load api `https://api.jquery.com/load/` or if you want the response alone then then you have to use jquery get api `https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/`. In the api's url's has to be replaced with respective '.do' struts urls